# Make /usr/bin/ld: cannot find local library

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

In my project I got a local library I am shipping with the project.

For that reason I included in the cmake file

```
LINK_DIRECTORIES(bls/build/src)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(bls/src)

LINK_DIRECTORIES(bls/build/contrib/relic/lib)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(bls/build/contrib/relic/include)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(bls/contrib/relic/include)
```

And then link it to the executables

```
add_executable(keygen_bls
        src/keygen_bls.cpp)
target_link_libraries(keygen_bls blstmp relic_s)
```

With this cmake runs fine. However when I run make then I get.

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lblstmp
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lrelic_s
```

Even though those libraries are at the places I specified above and not at /usr/bin/ld.

Project paths

[image]

Comment: Re: [`link_directories`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/link_directories.html) "_This command is rarely necessary and should be avoided where there are other choices._"

Comment: I do have the library in a relative path though in the project and not in an absolute path where it will always be found.

Comment: Ok, but you should be able to find the full path from the relative path using [`find_library`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_library.html#command:find_library) and then you could add a debug `message` showing what you've found before the `add_executable` command.

Comment: D you have an example for me?

Comment: Perhaps `find_library(RELIC_S_PATH relic_s bls/build/contrib/relic/lib)`  and `message(STATUS "RELIC_S_PATH " ${RELIC_S_PATH})` will show something useful.

Comment: RELIC_S_PATH RELIC_S_PATH-NOTFOUND

Comment: That should be useful info when debugging this. :-)

Comment: "Even though those libraries are at the places I specified above" - Above there is a specification of **several** places, and actual location of your libraries is not clear... Please, show **absolute path** to library files corresponded to `blstmp` and `relic_s` libraries. This absolute path should include also the exact filenames (`lib` prefix, if it is, and the library extension, `.a` or `.so`). Show also the **absolute path to the project** (a directory, where `CMakeLists.txt` is located): This directory is used for interpretation of the relative paths passed to `LINK_DIRECTORIES` command.

Comment: I've added more information in the head post.

Comment: I think I missed `PATHS` before the path in the `find_library` command above. Also, the actual path may need to be `"${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}/bls/build/contrib/relic/lib"`

Comment: CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH is empty for me, so I tried 
find_library(RELIC_S_PATH relic_s PATHS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bls/build/contrib/relic/lib)

Where the source dir is not empty, also resulted in not found

Comment: The file `libbls.a` could denote the library `bls` but not the library `blstmp` which you actually use for linking.

Comment: libblstmp.a is in the src folder (lthat's why I included bls/build/src in include directories)

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774593/cmake-link-to-external-library) post with several ways to link an external library to your project. Note, the answer with the most up-votes does **not** use `link_directories()`.

Comment: That brought me a bit further to: No rule to make target 'bls/build/src/libblstmp.a', needed by 'hotstuff-keygen_bls'.  Stop.

Comment: add_library( relic_s SHARED IMPORTED )
set_target_properties( relic_s PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bls/build/contrib/relic/lib/librelic_s.a )

Comment: I edited the full view in the post of the libraries and their locations.

Comment: The error message `No rule to make target 'bls/build/src/libblstmp.a'` tells that path you have specified in the `IMPORTED_LOCATION` property does actually **not exist**. Try to find out the **absolute path** of the library file (e.g. by picking it from the file's property, or from the shell), and **copy-paste** it to your `CMakeLists.txt` as a value for IMPORTED_LOCATION property. Note also, that `.a` is an extension for the `STATIC` library, not the `SHARED` one as you create IMPORTED target.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to the helpful comments leading me into the right direction I was able to get this to run:

```
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(bls/src)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(bls/build/contrib/relic/include)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(bls/contrib/relic/include)

add_library( blstmp STATIC IMPORTED )
set_target_properties( blstmp PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bls/build/src/libblstmp.a )

add_library( relic_s STATIC IMPORTED )
set_target_properties( relic_s PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bls/build/contrib/relic/lib/librelic_s.a )
```

Besides that, I'd noticed that git had excluded the library .a files when I copied them in that's why this wasn't working at the beginning either...